# AVFoundation can't scan low-contrast QR code

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, qr-code

The native `AVFoundation` QR code scanner just can't see a low-contrast QR code that I need to be able to scan. I know it's possible to scan the code though, because it works fine with WeChat's QR scanner.

How do I scan this QR code? Is there a way to adjust my `AVCaptureSession` to allow for lower-constrast QR codes? Is there a package I can use that would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with [Zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/index.html). Super easy to use, too. Here's a tiny demo (Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1): https://github.com/philipshen/ZBar-Demo-Swift-4

Answer (score 1):

Try to set capture quality to high.

```
session.sessionPreset = .high
```

Comment: setting to photo can improve it.